# edit buttons in specific rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

i have this table that contains appointments! i call it appoint and it has the above attributes: appontid,date,description,name. private key is the appointid. And the i have code to show all appointments with select, but i want in every row to have links for edit and delete. if someone choose edit in the specific appoint i want to keep rantevouid in order to send him a form to fill in and make the update to the appoint with the specific id.

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    include('dbConfig.php');
    $result = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM appoint") ;
    print '<table border="1">';
    print '<tr>';
    print '<td>ID appoint</td>';
    print '<td>date</td>';
    print '<td>description</td>';
    print '<td>name</td>';
    print '<td>EDIT</td>';
    print '<td>DELETE</td>';
    print '</tr>';
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array ($result))
    {
    print '<tr>';
    print '<td>'.$row['appointid'].'</td>';
    print '<td>'.$row['date'].'</td>';
    print '<td>'.$row['description'].'</td>';
    print '<td>'.$row['name'].'</td>';
    print '<td> <a href="edit.php">EDIT </a> </td>';
    print '<td> <a href="delete.php">DELETE</a> </td>';
    print '</tr>';
    }
    print '</table>'; 
    echo "</table>";
```

Now if someone for example press EDIT for the firs appointment i want to fill in a form with date description and name and the i want to update the appoint table at mysql. In order to do that i want to keep appointid which is specific in order to make update where id=$id1; Any ideas?

Can anyone tell me if this msql_query is correct? there is a form above and the id i take from another page as you told me

```
    <?php
    include('dbconfic.php');
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $id=$_GET['id'];
    $com=$_POST['comment'];
    $realdate=$_POST['date1'];
    $result=mysql_query("UPDATE appoint set comments='$com',date='$realdate' WHERE       'id=$id'") or die("QUERY error: ".mysql_error());
    echo"Row updated.";
    mysql_close();
    }
    ?>

    <form action="" method="post">
    <table>

    <tr>
    <td>NEW COMMENT</td>
    <td><input name="comment" type="text"> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>REAL DATE</td>
    <td><input name="date1" type="text" > </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

In that case your links need to have the value of the record to be edited/deleted:

```
print '<td> <a href="edit.php?id=' . $row['appointid'] . '">EDIT </a> </td>';
print '<td> <a href="delete.php?id=' . $row['appointid'] . '">DELETE</a> </td>';
```

Then on each subsequent page (edit.php and delete.php) you can get the ID of the appointment being edited/deleted from the query string:

```
$_GET['id']
```

With that ID you select the specific record being edited/deleted and handle it accordingly.  Note however that users *can* modify this value, so at the very least you want to:

1. Ensure the user has permission to edit/delete the record being requested *on the edit and delete pages*, not just when displaying the records on this page.
2. DO NOT use the value directly in a database query, that would expose a SQL injection vulnerability.  Make sure you validate the type/value and use it as a query parameter rather than just inject it into a SQL query as-is.

Comment: thnx man! i will try it! it is for the admin and so theri is no problem with permission! thnx again for your answer!